# Yii ajaxSubmitButton()

Tags: ajax, php, yii

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите с таким вопросом. У меня есть есть форма, в ней есть 1 поле, и есть одна переменная. Как мне можно отправить это всё через ajax? У меня не получается. Есть код:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
    Номер телефона(без +): <?php echo CHtml::textField('phone'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Продолжить', Yii::app()->createUrl('payment/qiwiajax'), array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'data'=>array(
            'amount'=>$amount,
        ),
        'success'=>'js:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }'
    )); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

В этом коде отправится amount, но поле от формы не отправится, а если я уберу этот массив, то отправятся данные из формы, но без amount, скажите как можно отправить и то и другое одним заопросом?

Answer (score 1):

в class CHtml есть такой код

```
public static function ajax($options)
    {
...........................
        if(!isset($options['data']) && isset($options['type']))
            $options['data']=new CJavaScriptExpression('jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()');
............................
    }
```

То есть, если вы указали 'data' - то форма во внимание не берется.

```
Поэтому 2 пути:
 1. В форму добавляем скрытое поле с нужной вам инфой, тогда 'data' не указываем.
 3. Ручками собираем  'data' в коде.
```

Да и еще 'type' - можете  не указывать, так как он ставится  всегда в  POST

```
public static function ajaxSubmitButton($label,$url,$ajaxOptions=array(),$htmlOptions=array())
    {
        $ajaxOptions['type']='POST';
        $htmlOptions['type']='submit';
        return self::ajaxButton($label,$url,$ajaxOptions,$htmlOptions);
    }
```